# Setup a cronjob from commandline

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I want to setup a cronjob to execute a shell script every 5 minutes on my ubuntu server. So I enter the following in the command line:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

That returns status code `137` and lets me edit the crontab in vi editor. I enter the following

```
*/15 * * * * myScript.sh
```

After that I enter `;wq` and I get following message:

```
crontab: "/usr/bin/sensible-editor" exited with status 1
```

Whats wrong?  How can I enter a cronjob?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulate cron jobs without using crontab on OS X 10.7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335432/manipulate-cron-jobs-without-using-crontab-on-os-x-10-7)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the correct sequence for exiting vi is

```
:wq
```

not ;wq

also, try changing the editor to something more user-friendly, e.g. nano

```
# export EDITOR="/usr/bin/nano"
# crontab -e
```