# Manipulate cron jobs without using crontab on OS X 10.7?

Tags: macos, cron

Not even sure it's possible but I was trying to find a way to add/remove/edit cron jobs in BASH without using crontab.
I'm trying to build a UI front-end to interact with cron but, to my knowledge, crontab requires user input since any change must be done within an editor (vi, nano...)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you actually want a cron job (rather than a launch daemon as @Jerry suggested), the `crontab` command can be used to script changes to a user's crontab file:

```
crontab -l >tempfile  # Dump out the current crontab
# change tempfile as needed -- add/remove entries, etc
crontab <tempfile  # Load the modified crontab
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the preferred method to manage daemons is via `launchctl`.  It will actually manage `cron` as needed.  Without knowing exactly what you want to do, that's my suggestion for where to start.

Comment: this is definitely the idiomatic way of managing scheduled re-occurring tasks in OSX.

Comment: Agreed. Not what I asked though.